# Submersion with compact level sets is a fiber bundle

Tags: fiber-bundles, foliations

In the book "Foliations I" Candel & Conlon, the exercise 1.1.3 is as follow:

If $\partial M = \emptyset = \partial B$ and $B$ is connected, prove that the submersion $f:M\rightarrow B$ with compact level sets is a fiber bundle.

How to solve it?

Comment: First, you should prove that a submersion with compact fibers is a proper map. Then, the [Ehresmann Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_lemma) states that a proper surjective submersion is a fiber bundle. There is a nice [series of exercises](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~behre001/AoM/AoM_exercises_11.pdf) by Stefan Behrens that contains a walkthrough of the proof of Ehresmann's lemma.

Answer (score 8):

The assertion is false without additional assumptions.

Suppose $B$ is connected and consider any smooth finite covering map $M\to B$. Remove a point from $M$. The result is still a smooth submersion with compact fibers. It is not a fiber bundle because the fiber size is not constant. For an explicit example take the trivial two-fold cover $B\amalg B\to B$ and remove a point upstairs.

The problem in the above example is disconnectedness of the fibers. If the fibers are both compact *and* connected, things fall into place.

**Theorem.** A submersion with compact connected fibers is proper.

This follows from the topological theory of monotone-light factorizations. See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/186767/69037).

**Theorem.** (Ehresmann.) A proper surjective submersion is a fiber bundle.

This is a fundamental theorem in differential geometry whose proofs rely on the concept of flows along vector fields.